# How can I use a url in R?

Tags: r, url, text, r-markdown

I have a text in r and I need that the url appears blue can you help me?

```
plot.new()
       
mtext("Example, URL: http://www.google.co", side = 4, las = 1, cex = 0.7)
```

I need the URL Google in blue in my plot how can I do this without change the black color in the word "Example"?

Thanks a lot :3

Comment: A not very good solution because you have to give the coordinates with `at`: `plot.new(); mtext(c("Example URL: ", "http://www.google.com"), col = c("black" , "blue"), side = 3, cex = 0.7, at = c(0, 0.35))`

Comment: Thank a lot, you solved my problem :3